# How long does #delay in the delayed_job library in Rails last?

Tags: multithreading, sidekiq

I'm using sidekiq and I just read this documentation:

```
ActiveRecord

Use delay, delay_for(interval), or delay_until(time) to asynchronously execute arbitrary methods on your ActiveRecord classes.

User.delay.delete_old_users('some', 'params')
User.delay_for(2.weeks).whatever
User.delay_until(2.weeks.from_now).whatever
```

How long does the standard delay last for? Or does it just immediately fire off a job in another thread?

And would you say this is an accurate definition of thread:

> a thread of execution is the smallest sequence of programmed
>   instructions that can be managed independently by a scheduler, which
>   is typically a part of the operating system....

and better:

> A thread is an execution context, which is all the information a CPU
>   needs to execute a stream of instructions.
>
> Suppose you're reading a book, and you want to take a break right now,
>   but you want to be able to come back and resume reading from the exact
>   point where you stopped. One way to achieve that is by jotting down
>   the page number, line number, and word number. So your execution
>   context for reading a book is these 3 numbers.
>
> If you have a roommate, and she's using the same technique, she can
>   take the book while you're not using it, and resume reading from where
>   she stopped. Then you can take it back, and resume it from where you
>   were.
>
> Threads work in the same way. A CPU is giving you the illusion that
>   it's doing multiple computations at the same time. It does that by
>   spending a bit of time on each computation. It can do that because it
>   has an execution context for each computation. Just like you can share
>   a book with your friend, many tasks can share a CPU.
>
> On a more technical level, an execution context (therefore a thread)
>   consists of the values of the CPU's registers.
>
> Last: threads are different from processes. A thread is a context of
>   execution, while a process is a bunch of resources associated with a
>   computation. A process can have one or many threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delay means "do this work as soon as possible somewhere else".  The job is enqueued into Redis and might be executed in the next millisecond or hours from now - you don't know.